# Построить текст по одной линии

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Здравствуйте, учусь верстать сайты, делаю меню для сайта, не могу построить текст по одной линии

Сейчас:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимый результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Прикладываю разметку

CSS:

```
p.menutag {
  font-family: 'oswald', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 7.5%;
  color: #808080;
  display: inline;
}

div.offset {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 7.5%;
}


.iconsmargin {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-top: 3%;
  font-size: 1.6em;
}

p.menulinks {
  font-family: 'roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.375em;
  position: relative;
  left: 3%;
  color: #303030;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
}

div.lineonmenu {
  height: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 10%;
  position: relative;
  background: #b8b8b8;
  margin-top: 1%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="offset">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <p class="menutag">Menu</p>
    <div class="lineonmenu"></div>
    <i class="fa fa-home iconsmargin" aria-hidden="true"></i><p class="menulinks">Home</p>
    <div class="lineonmenu"></div>
    <i class="fa fa-address-card iconsmargin" aria-hidden="true"></i><p class="menulinks">About me</p>
    <div class="lineonmenu"></div>
    <i class="fa fa-briefcase iconsmargin" aria-hidden="true"></i><p class="menulinks">Portfolio</p>
    <div class="lineonmenu"></div>
    <i class="fa fa-comments-o iconsmargin" aria-hidden="true"></i><p class="menulinks">Comments</p>
    <div class="lineonmenu"></div>
    <i class="fa fa-envelope iconsmargin" aria-hidden="true"></i><p class="menulinks">Contact info</p>
    <div class="lineonmenu"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.menu-list {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background: #f7f7f7;    
    max-width: 350px;
}

.menu-list > li {
    list-style: none;
}

.menu-list > li > a {
    display: block;
    color: #000;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 40px;
    position: relative;
    transition: .3s;
}

.menu-list > li > a i {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 5px;
    width: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.menu-list > li > a:hover {
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul class="menu-list">
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-address-card" aria-hidden="true"></i> Menu item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-briefcase" aria-hidden="true"></i> Menu item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-address-card" aria-hidden="true"></i> Menu item 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-briefcase" aria-hidden="true"></i> Menu item 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Вариант с использованием псевдоэлементов

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.menu-list {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: #f7f7f7;
  max-width: 350px;
}

.menu-list>li {
  list-style: none;
}

.menu-list>li>a {
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 40px;
  position: relative;
  transition: .3s;
}

.menu-list>li>a:before {
  content: '\f2b9';
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  left: 5px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.menu-list>li:nth-child(2)>a:before {
  content: '\f2cd';
}

.menu-list>li:nth-child(3)>a:before {
  content: '\f2b5';
}

.menu-list>li:nth-child(4)>a:before {
  content: '\f2d9';
}

.menu-list>li>a:hover {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<ul class="menu-list">
  <li><a href="#">Menu item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu item 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu item 4</a></li>
</ul>
```